# Testing for players in particles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Quick question.

After a thorough google and Arqade search before, I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a player was inside of a particle effect. For example if I had the command:

```
/particle happyVillager 10 15 12 1 1 1 25 25 25
```

Running on a clock, and a player walked through 10 15 12, it would output a redstone signal. Perhaps an execute command or maybe this is simply impossible? Any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particles cannot be detected/targeted. If you know the location that the particles are being created, you can merely target players at that location:

```
/testfor @a[10,15,12,1]
```

I should mention that you have a stray `25` at the end of your `/particle` command, when it should either be `normal` or `force` (otherwise defaulting to `normal`).

---

An alternative to using `/particle` in 1.9 is to use an AreaEffectCloud entity, which creates particles at a particular location as well as optionally applying custom potion effects to players who enter the area.

```
/summon AreaEffectCloud 10 15 12 {Particle:"happyVillager",Radius:1.0f,Duration:2147483647}
```

You could target players via `/execute` and the AreaEffectCloud:

```
/execute @e[type=AreaEffectCloud] ~ ~ ~ /say @a[r=1]
```

Alternatively (and more accurately), you could cause the entity to apply an inert custom effect to the player and detect players with that effect. For example, the following gives the player a Resistance effect with an amplifier of -1, which means 0% damage reduction (essentially rendering the *actual* effect useless, but we can still detect it appropriately).

```
/summon AreaEffectCloud 10 15 12 {Particle:"happyVillager",Radius:1.0f,Effects:[{Id:11b,Duration:10,Amplifier:-1b,ShowParticles:0b}],Duration:2147483647}
```

For detection:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=inCloud] remove inCloud
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!inCloud] add inCloud {ActiveEffects:[{Id:11b,Amplifier:-1b}]}
```

Comment: The resistance effect here would overwrite existing resistance effects, right? Wouldn't something like Bad Luck 0 work better in this case?

Comment: @MrLemon That's correct, it would indeed have to overwrite. Bad Luck would also end up needing to overwrite as well, so it's mainly about what would work best for the OP since unfortunately there is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Still think a `/testfor` in radius works well. Interesting idea, though!

Comment: @Skylinerw Thanks for your thorough answer. Could you explain the detection part a little? I understand I need to first add the scoreboard, and would second command you give (in detection) need to run on a clock? Sorry, scoreboards are my weakness :)

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN There are no objectives being used. `/scoreboard tags` is a new feature added in 1.9 and has essentially no relation to scoreboards other than its use with the `/scoreboard` command's syntax (which is unfortunately misleading). Both commands for detection need to be run on a clock: the first removes the label so that players don't *always* have the label, and the second one gives the label. See [the wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Tags_commands) for more info on `/scoreboard tags` syntax.

Comment: @Skylinerw Hm. Doesn't seem to work for me, but I probably just did something wrong. I got the execute way to work, however. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN [Image of clock](http://i.imgur.com/VnZDAbq.png). Place commands in presented order from left to right, append any further commands you want. You target players, for example, with `@a[tag=inCloud]`. If you're changing the commands, you'd have to clarify that.